# ddslick value undefined - unable to pass values on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am unable to pass values from a dropdown menu to the addtocart() function, as soon as ddslick comes into play.

> > As soon as I add e.g. $('#list1').ddslick();)

It throws an "undefined" data error. I changed the line above to

```js
$('#list1').ddslick({
    showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(data){
        alert(data.selectedData.value);
    }   
});
```

and get the correct output in this prompted alert, but still cannot pass the value on. In my understanding, the following code of the addtocart() function

```js
document.getElementById('list1').value
```

needs to be replaced by something in the direction of

```js
document.getElementById('list1').value
```

I am unable to get it running though.

Here is the complete code:

```js
$('#list1').ddslick();
$('#list2').ddslick();


function addToCart() {
  var school = document.getElementById('list1').value
  var item = document.getElementById('list2').value
  alert('school: ' + school + ' item: ' + item)
  CartJS.addItem(school, 2);
}
```

```css
<style class="cp-pen-styles"><style class="cp-pen-styles">*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import "compass/css3";
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  float: left;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#options,
.dd-select,
.dd-options {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.dd-selected-text,
.dd-option-text {
  line-height: 64px !important;
}

.dd-select {
  background: #fff !important;
  border-color: #d1d3d4 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dd-selected {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="name"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="password"],
select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.min.js'></script>

<ul class="flex-container">

  <li class="flex-item">
    <section class="grid__spans-25">
      <select id="list1">
       <option value="9107763265579" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 3</option>
    </select>

    </section>
  </li>

  <li class="flex-item">
    <section class="grid__spans-25">
      <select id="list2">
       <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 3</option>
    </select>

    </section>
  </li>

</ul>

<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addToCart()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fixed code

```js
$('#list1').ddslick();
$('#list2').ddslick();


function addToCart() {
//      var school = document.getElementById('list1').value
//      var item = document.getElementById('list2').value

  var list1Selection = $('#list1').data('ddslick').selectedData;
  var school = list1Selection.value + " / " + list1Selection.text 
  

  var list2Selection = $('#list2').data('ddslick').selectedData;
  var item = list2Selection.value + " / " + list2Selection.text 

  alert('school: [' + school + '] item: [' + item + ']')
  // CartJS.addItem(school, 2);
}
```

```css
<style class="cp-pen-styles"><style class="cp-pen-styles">*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import "compass/css3";
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  float: left;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#options,
.dd-select,
.dd-options {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.dd-selected-text,
.dd-option-text {
  line-height: 64px !important;
}

.dd-select {
  background: #fff !important;
  border-color: #d1d3d4 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dd-selected {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="name"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="password"],
select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.min.js'></script>

<ul class="flex-container">

  <li class="flex-item">
    <section class="grid__spans-25">
      <select id="list1">
       <option value="9107763265579" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 3</option>
    </select>

    </section>
  </li>

  <li class="flex-item">
    <section class="grid__spans-25">
      <select id="list2">
       <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">item 3</option>
    </select>

    </section>
  </li>

</ul>

<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addToCart()">
```

Comment: It's not working (even though it does here). I don't get an alert at all now (which I did before) and if I comment out CartJS.addItem(school, 2); it doesn't add an item either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you can call the addToCart function from inside the click function.

```
$('#list1').ddslick({
    showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(data){
        alert(data.selectedData.value);
        addToCart(data.selectedData.value);
    }   
});

function addToCart(item){
    CartJS.addItem(item,2);
}
```

Or if the user needs to select one item from each dropdown and then call addToCart, maybe save the values of list1 and list2 in an object and access the values on addToCart:

```
var listState = {
    list1val: null,
    list2val: null
}

$('#list1').ddslick({
    showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(data){
        listState.list1Val = data.selectedData.value,
    }   
});

$('#list2').ddslick({
    showSelectedHTML: false,
    onSelected: function(data){
        listState.list2Val = data.selectedData.value,
    }   
});

function addToCart(item){
    var school = listState.list1Val;
    var item = listState.list2Val;
    console.log(listState);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to pass have the user first select something and then click on a button that triggers the addtoCart function. Your 2nd example doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: As soon as I add this code, the drop-down feature to display images vanishes.

Comment: @FatTwin I'm not sure what your drop-down feature to display images is, but my 2nd example is meant to illustrate how the issue might be addressed and not meant to be copy-pasted. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Looks like @Nosyara's example might be more specific to your code.

Comment: His code doesn't work on my end unfortunately. What ddslick does is add a picture next to any dropdown line. I basically can click on it and it displays 5 country flags I can select from instead of just working with text.

Comment: @FatTwin if you can, get your code working in a jsfiddle and we can debug on a real example

Comment: I seems to be something Shopify-related. I created a new page, added the same working code and don't get it working.